# Having trouble getting current time as a variable in the little script

Tags: jquery

Trying to get time dynamically for the now field of this script. I have tried using $.now() and Date() but can't seem to find the right combination. PS... I suck at JQuery as I am a newb so this is why I am here

The countdown works... but always starts at the time stamp listed as now every time the page is refreshed. The variable here is fed to primary script which I did not write.

```js
$('.countdown').final_countdown({
  start: 1686226400,
  end: 1696226400,
  now: 1686226400,
  seconds: {
    borderColor: '#5677fc',
    borderWidth: '3'
  },
  minutes: {
    borderColor: '#7e57c2',
    borderWidth: '3'
  },
  hours: {
    borderColor: '#4db6ac',
    borderWidth: '3'
  },
  days: {
    borderColor: '#d81b60',
    borderWidth: '3'
  }
}, function() {});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Tried setting var now =  $.now()... but did not seem to work for me

Comment: What is `final_countdown()`? Is it from a plugin? If so, which one? Where are you attempting to use your `now` variable?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and plugin to the snippet I made you

Comment: `$,now()` : *Note: This API has been deprecated in jQuery 3.3; please use the native Date.now() method instead.*  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to convert the output from milliseconds to seconds. Try:

```
now: Math.floor($.now() / 1000),
```

Comment: That actually did the trick. I knew I was missing something silly. Thanks a bunch!